# Cannot Modify Header Information error

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am using Bazar theme and woo commerce. I tried adding a new products but I get this error saying:

> 'cannot modify header Information - header already sent by (output started at c:\wamp\www\WordPress\wp-content\themes\bazar\theme\woocommerce.php:809) in c:\wamp\www\WordPress\wp-includes\pluggable.php on line 1207'.

I am new to PHP and WordPress and I don't know what this mean. I didn't edit any PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

When you see any error that says "pluggable" it usually means the error resides on a particular plugin in WP. You can disable all plugins except WooCommerce and see if it corrects it. If it doesn't, try changing the theme to the 2015 theme and see if the error goes away. If it does when changing themes then the problem is with your theme.

Answer (score 0):

this is line 1207:
`header("Location: $location", true, $status);`
You are getting redirected for some reason, could be a rogue plugin or a hack.